# Will dumping, creating a new database, and then restoring Django auth and system related tables cause any problems?

Tags: python, django

I put my first Django site online eight months ago. It was both a proof of concept as well as my first experience with Django. Fast forward eight months, I have validated my idea, but since it was a proof of concept and my first Django project, the code is pretty messy. Essentially, I am going to be re-writing the majority of the site, including re-engineering the models.

This is all fine and good. I have all my new models planned out. Essentially, I am going to create a new database to develop off of and let South manage any new database schema changes I make.

It is important to note two things:

1. I will *not* be creating a new project, just a new database.
2. This will be the first time I am incorporating South into the project and I would prefer to start with fresh models and a fresh database.

My question is, when I create the new database, will importing the contents of the old auth_* and django_* tables into the new auth_* and django_* tables create any problems? I have had some users register using the original proof of concept and I don't want to lose their information. I've never had to do this before so I'm not sure if there will be any repercussions.

Comment: are you doing an SQL dump, or a per-app serialized (json, xml) dump with the `dumpdata` command?

Comment: What is the mapping between new and old models? Is it trivial, or a PhD thesis?

Comment: @GonzaloDelgado I am doing an SQL dump using the mysqldump command

Comment: @PeterRowell The custom models that I am developing aren't an issue. That is an easy mapping. And the mapping itself doesn't concern more. I am just worried about breaking the core Django tables, such as django_content_type or auth_user.

Comment: @AdrianRosebrock: the only thing that comes to mind is that 1.5 has a new User model setup so you can define your own. I haven't worked with it yet, but there's a chance that field names may have changed name/length/definition/???.

Comment: @PeterRowell Luckily I have not modified the User model so everything is okay :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use sql dump, such as

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword db_name table_name > xxxx.sql
mysql -uusername -ppassword new_db_name < xxxx.sql
```

The database's side is fine，if your backend is some other db，you can still find the similar commands.

For a new db, i think you need to export/import auth_user, i'm not quite sure if you need other contents in django_* tables. You can do this step by step, and see whether the new project works.

Comment: THanks for the help. I created a new database, let South handle the migrations, and then imported the contents of the old auth_user table. Everything worked fine. :-)